# Mark multiple messages as read in Inbox by Gmail

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

Is there a way to select multiple messages and mark them as read in [Inbox by Gmail](https://inbox.google.com/)?

I can select multiple messages, but I can't find any way to mark them as read. I can mark them done, but not read. The key to mark them read is not even in the shortcut list.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Apparently, you can't. You can't even manually mark a single message as read without actually reading it.

I expect that this is by design. If you're done with the message, then you should mark it "Done". If you don't need it right now but what to handle it later, you should "Snooze" it. If you don't ever need the message again, you can always "Trash" it. (All three actions are available when you have multiple messages selected.)

(If you think this is an oversight, you should use the "Send Feedback" feature to let them know. The app is in preview testing, after all.)

Comment: To add: you can always do a search for `is:unread` to see all mails you have not yet read.

Comment: Any updates on this? Can you now mark a single message as read?

Comment: Even if it's by design, marking as "done" should probably mark as read as well, but it currently doesn't. This is super annoying in search. To fix this, you can actually search "is:unread is:done" in old Gmail, select all, and "mark as read".

Answer (score 1):

Since as of now there is no such a feature/option like that, what I do is:

1. Click Gmail on left sidebar (that will take you to regular gmail)
2. Type `is:unread` in to search box (which will bring you all the
   unread emails)
3. Check all
4. Click `More`
5. Mark them as Read

This is pretty quick work around. Hope it helps.